# Why is save() is changing the model value?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Here is where I save the game:

```
public function storeGame() {
    $player = new Player(['player_name' => Request::get('host_name')]);
    $player->save();

    $game = new Game(Request::all());
    $game->host_id = $player->id;
    $game->save();
    $player->game_id = $game->id;
    $player->save();

    return redirect('lobby');
}
```

Here is the eloquent relationship:

```
class Game extends Model {

    protected $table = 'games';

    protected $fillable = ['game_name','password','round_time','num_rounds','num_players','roles_bool'];

    protected $hidden = ['password'];

    public function host() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Player', 'id');
    }

    public function players() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Player', 'id');
    }
}
```

The problem is when I save the game, the value of the host id is changing. These are the results of a var_dump() after saving.

```
$game->host_id:
int 2
$game->host->id:
string '1' (length=1)
```

Why is this happening and how do I stop it?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably loaded related host object before and it hasn't been "refreshed" after you changed host id. Actually you shouldn't change relations ids directly, there are dedicated methods to do that: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models

Answer (score 1):

Duncan - I'm thinking this has something to do with your `Host` relationship. I don't see a `host_id` anywhere in your fillable fields on your Games model.

You should have a `host_id` fillable field on your `Games` model and then the relationship would look like this:

```
public function host() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Player', 'host_id');
    }
```